# Can cond support TF ops with side effects?

Tags: tensorflow

The (source code) documentation for `tf.cond` is unclear on whether the functions to be performed when the predicate is evaluated can have side effects or not. I've done some tests but I'm getting conflicting results. For example the code below does not work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])
count = tf.Variable(0)
adder = count.assign_add(1)
subtractor = count.assign_sub(2)

my_op = control_flow_ops.cond(pred, lambda: adder, lambda: subtractor)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

my_op.eval(feed_dict={pred: True})
count.eval() # returns -1

my_op.eval(feed_dict={pred: False})
count.eval() # returns -2
```

I.e. no matter what value the predicate evaluates to, both functions are getting run, and so the net result is a subtraction of 1. On the other hand, this code snippet does work, where the only difference is that I add new ops to the graph every time `my_op` is called:

```
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, [])
count = tf.Variable(0)

my_op = control_flow_ops.cond(pred, lambda:count.assign_add(1), lambda:count.assign_sub(2))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

my_op.eval(feed_dict={pred: False})
count.eval() # returns -2

my_op.eval(feed_dict={pred: True})
count.eval() # returns -1
```

Not sure why creating new ops every time works while the other case doesn't, but I'd obviously rather not be adding nodes as the graph will eventually become too big.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your second version—where the `assign_add()` and `assign_sub()` ops are creating inside the lambdas passed to `cond()`—is the correct way to do this. Fortunately, each of the two lambdas is only evaluated once, during the call to `cond()`, so your graph will not grow without bound.

Essentially what `cond()` does is the following:

1. Create a `Switch` node, which forwards its input to only one of two outputs, depending on the value of `pred`. Let's call the outputs `pred_true` and `pred_false`. (They have the same value as `pred` but that's unimportant since this is never directly evaluated.)
2. Build the subgraph corresponding to the `if_true` lambda, where all of the nodes have a control dependency on `pred_true`.
3. Build the subgraph corresponding to the `if_false` lambda, where all of the nodes have a control dependency on `pred_false`.
4. Zip together the lists of return values from the two lambdas, and create a `Merge` node for each of these. A `Merge` node takes two inputs, of which only one is expected to be produced, and forwards it to its output.
5. Return the tensors that are the outputs of the `Merge` nodes.

This means you can run your second version, and be content that the graph remains a fixed size, regardless of how many steps you run.

The reason your first version doesn't work is that, when a `Tensor` is captured (like `adder` or `subtractor` in your example), an additional `Switch` node is added to enforce the logic that the value of the tensor is only forwarded to the branch that actually executes. This is an artifact of how TensorFlow combines feed-forward dataflow and control flow  in its execution model. The result is that the captured tensors (in this case the results of the `assign_add` and `assign_sub`) will always be evaluated, even if they aren't used, and you'll see their side effects. This is something we need to document better, and [as Michael says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934516/3574081), we're going to make this more usable in future.

Answer (score 9):

The second case works because you have added the ops within the cond: this causes them to conditionally execute.

The first case it is analogous to saying:

```
adder = (count += 1)
subtractor = (count -= 2)
if (cond) { adder } else { subtractor }
```

Since adder and subtractor are outside the conditional, they are always executed.

The second case is more like saying

```
if (cond) { adder = (count += 1) } else { subtractor = (count -= 2) }
```

which in this case does what you expected.

We realize that the interaction between side effects and (somewhat) lazy evaluation is confusing, and we have a medium-term goal to make things more uniform. But the important thing to understand for now is that we do not do true lazy evaluation: the conditional acquires a dependency on every quantity defined outside the conditional that is used within either branch.