# How to make an if statement using a boolean Tensor

Tags: tensorflow

How do I make an if statement using a boolean tensor?  To be more precise, I'm trying to compare a tensor of size 1 to a constant, checking to see if the value in the tensor is less than the constant.  I figured out I have to make the constant its own size 1 tensor and use [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#less) method to check if the first tensor is less than the second tensor, but I'm not sure how to make the resulting boolean tensor fit correctly into an if statement.  Just putting it in as the query for the if statement makes if statement always return true.

EDIT:  This is more or less what the code looked like.  However, I'm getting the error `'bool' object has no attribute 'name'` regardless of whether it has parameters or not, which makes me think the problem is instead that it's not returning a TensorFlow object.

```
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def if_true(x, y, z):
  #act on x, y, and z
  return True

def if_false():
  return False

# Will be `tf.cond()` in the next release.
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops
from functools import partial
x = ...
y = ...
z = ...

result = control_flow_ops.cond(pred, partial(if_true, x, y, z), if_false)
```

Comment: I think you need to return `Tensor` objects from your `if_true` and `if_false` functions. These can simply be `tf.constant(True)` and `tf.constant(False)` respectively. If your actions on `x`, `y`, and `z` have side effects, be sure to add a control dependency on them to the returned tensor, or they may not execute.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the original conditional.  I may have found a workaround though, for my specific variables.

Comment: Hmm, if getting the output as a `Tensor` doesn't meet your needs, then I presume you aren't feeding the result to a further TensorFlow subgraph. In that case, it might be simplest to use `sess.run()` and a straightforward Python `if` statement.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You need to use [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) to get a Python boolean, but there are other ways to achieve the same result that might be more efficient.

It looks like you've already figured out how to get a boolean tensor from your value, but for the benefit of other readers, it would look something like this:

```
computed_val = ...
constant_val = tf.constant(37.0)
pred = tf.less(computed_val, constant_val)  # N.B. Types of the two args must match
```

The next part is how to use it as a conditional. The simplest thing to do is to use a Python `if` statement, but to do that you must **evaluate** the tensor `pred` using [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run):

```
sess = tf.Session()

if sess.run(pred):
  # Do something.
else:
  # Do something else.
```

One caveat about using a Python `if` statement is that you have to evaluate the whole expression up to `pred`, which makes it tricky to reuse intermediate values that have already been computed. I'd like to draw your attention to two other ways you can compute conditional expressions using TensorFlow, which don't require you to evaluate the predicate and get a Python value back.

The first way uses the [`tf.select()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#select) op to conditionally pass through values from two tensors passed as arguments:

```
pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)  # Can be any computed boolean expression.
val_if_true = tf.constant(28.0)
val_if_false = tf.constant(12.0)
result = tf.select(pred, val_if_true, val_if_false)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result, feed_dict={pred: True})   # ==> 28.0
sess.run(result, feed_dict={pred: False})  # ==> 12.0
```

The `tf.select()` op works element-wise on all of its arguments, which allows you to combine values from the two input tensors. See [its documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#select) for more details. The drawback of `tf.select()` is that it evaluates both `val_if_true` and `val_if_false` before computing the result, which might be expensive if they are complicated expressions.

The second way uses the [`tf.cond()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c1ab21a6ff9d267d6d93db149720bd1e2ad13c9/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py#L1103) op, which conditionally evaluates one of two expressions. This is particularly useful if the expressions are expensive, and it is essential if they [have side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931121/can-cond-support-tf-ops-with-side-effects). The basic pattern is to specify two Python functions (or lambda expressions) that build subgraphs that will execute on the true or false branches:

```
# Define some large matrices
a = ...
b = ...
c = ...

pred = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

def if_true():
  return tf.matmul(a, b)

def if_false():
  return tf.matmul(b, c)

# Will be `tf.cond()` in the next release.
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

result = tf.cond(pred, if_true, if_false)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(result, feed_dict={pred: True})   # ==> executes only (a x b)
sess.run(result, feed_dict={pred: False})  # ==> executes only (b x c)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make one of those functions in the .cond have parameters?  I want the if_true to have 3 parameters, but I can't figure out how to pass any through.  If I use partial or lambda, it tells me the bool object has no attribute name, which i suspect is from Tensorflow trying to create the graph.

Oh, and my if_true and if_false are returning a boolean, which is why it's a bool object.

Comment: The `if_true`/`if_false` functions themselves shouldn't have parameters, but you can capture values from the enclosing scope. I'm not sure I have a good picture of your code from your comment, so perhaps it would be better to update your question with the current version.

Comment: Edited with the new code.  Tried moving the information involving the parameters out of the function and in a normal if statement, and I'm getting the same error, so the problem must be because I'm not returning a TensorFlow object.  Problem is, the information that depends on this boolean isn't in a TensorFlow object.

Comment: There is no need using control_flow_ops.cond. tf.cond plays the same role now.

Comment: @mrry, here what is the difference between `tf.cond(pred, if_true, if_false)` and `tf.cond(pred, if_true(), if_false())` why I use `tf.cond(pred, if_true(), if_false())`  it comes out the error `fn1 must be callable` ? Thank you.

Comment: @karl_TUM When you pass `if_true` as an argument, that passes the function itself; now tensorflow can call that function. However, when you pass `if_true()` as an argument, you've already evaluated the function. You are actually passing *the return value* from the function (you can check out the difference by doing `print(if_true)` vs `print(if_true())`). Whenever using a function as an argument in Python, make sure **not** to put the parentheses.