# Parameterized model over output functions using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, parameterized

Is it possible to make parameterized model over output functions using tensorflow? And how?

example: 
I want model with used softmax function at the end, so

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(output_potentials, y))
```

but then I would like to try sigmoidal output and mean squares, in that case:

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.pow(tf.sub(tf.nn.sigmoid(output_potentials), y), 2.0))
```

my question is, how can one make parametrized model with specification of cost function? I don't have tensorflow placeholders before calling constructor for such model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both functions in the graph, and then during evaluation call either one or the other. The evaluation framework will select subset of the graph that's needed for the particular version of cost during evaluation

```
cost1 = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(output_potentials, y))
cost2 = tf.reduce_sum(
    tf.pow(tf.sub(tf.nn.sigmoid(output_potentials), y), 2.0))
sess.run([cost1])
sess.run([cost2])
```

Comment: You could put control flow logic into the graph itself using a experimental feature described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34964654/419116 . Not sure that gains you anything though