# Tensorflow: Random selection of masks

Tags: tensorflow

I know that [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959853/how-to-make-an-if-statement-using-a-boolean-tensor) already gives some nice examples about conditionals in tensorflow, but I'm still struggling how to solve my issue of randomly selecting among several different masks in tensorflow.
Right now I can only select between two mask tensors `a` and `b`:

```
rand_num = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=2.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None)
def if_true():
     return b
def if_false():
     return a
mask_sel = tf.cond(tf.less(rand_num , tf.constant(1.0)),if_true,if_false)
```

(I still find it weird that one needs to define these two helper functions, but not using them weirdly throws an error.)
Now the question: Lets say I have 4 mask tensors (a,b,c,d) or more to randomly select, what would be the best way to do that in tensorflow?

In python that would be

```
rand_num = np.random.uniform(low=0,high=4.0)
if (rand_num < 1.0):
    mask_sel = a
elif(rand_num < 2.0):
    mask_sel = b
elif(rand_num < 3.0):
    mask_sel = c
else
    mask_sel = d
```

Answer (score 0):

About the helper functions, they are useful because they allow tensorflow to know which operations will run under each condition, this way it can optimize by running only the selected branch and ignoring the other. Operations outside the helper functions but used by any of them will always be run before `tf.cond` runs.

The other options is to use `tf.select`; you won't need the helper functions here but it will always evaluate both sides before running `tf.select` which can be inefficient if you don't need to.

Now for the main problem 'selecting from more than 2 tesnors', you can use multiple options:

1- Recursively nesting `tf.cond` operations:

```
def select_from_list(selector, tensor_list):
    length = len(tensor_list)
    if length == 0:
        raise ValueError('List is empty')
    elif length == 1:
        return tensor_list[0]
    else:
        half = length // 2
        return tf.cond(tf.less(selector, float(half)), lambda: select_from_list(selector, tensor_list[:half]), lambda: select_from_list(selector - half, tensor_list[half:]))
```

2- Using `tf.case`:

```
def select_from_list(selector, tensor_list):
    length = len(tensor_list)
    if length == 0:
        raise ValueError('List is empty')
    elif length == 1:
        return tensor_list[0]
    else:
        def fn(tensor):
            return lambda: tensor
        pred_fn_pairs = [(tf.less(selector, float(i+1)), fn(tensor)) for i, tensor in enumerate(tensor_list)]
        return tf.case(pred_fn_pairs, default=lambda:tensor_list[-1])
```

You can test any of them using:

```
def test(selector, value_list, sess):
    return select_from_list(float(selector), [tf.constant(value) for value in value_list]).eval(session = sess)

sess = tf.Session()
test(3.5, [4,2,6,7,5], sess)
```

This should return `7`