# TensorFlow: How to write multistep decay

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is multistep decay in Caffe. It is calculated as `base_lr * gamma ^ (floor(step))` where `step` is incremented after each of your decay steps. For example with `[100, 200]` decay steps and `global step=101` I want get `base_lr * gamma ^ 1`, for `global step=201` and more I want get `base_lr * gamma ^ 2` and so on.

I tried to implement it based on exponential decay sources but I can do nothing. Here is code of exponential decay (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/learning_rate_decay.py#L27 ):

```
def exponential_decay(learning_rate, global_step, decay_steps, decay_rate,
staircase=False, name=None):
  with ops.name_scope(name, "ExponentialDecay",
                      [learning_rate, global_step,
                       decay_steps, decay_rate]) as name:
    learning_rate = ops.convert_to_tensor(learning_rate, name="learning_rate")
    dtype = learning_rate.dtype
    global_step = math_ops.cast(global_step, dtype)
    decay_steps = math_ops.cast(decay_steps, dtype)
    decay_rate = math_ops.cast(decay_rate, dtype)
    p = global_step / decay_steps
    if staircase:
      p = math_ops.floor(p)
return math_ops.mul(learning_rate, math_ops.pow(decay_rate, p), name=name)
```

I must pass `decay_steps` as some sort of array - python array or Tensor. Also I must(?) pass `current_decay_step`  (`step` in above formula).

**First option:** In pure python without tensors it is very simple:

```
decay_steps.append(global_step)
p = sorted(decay_steps).index(global_step) # may be there must be `+1` or `-1`. I hope that main idea is clear
```

I cant' do it because there is no sort in TF. I don't know how many time it take to implement it.

**Second option**: something like code below. It doesn't work for many reasons. Firstly I don't know how to pass args to funtion in `tf.cond`. Secondly, it may not work even if I will pass args: [Can cond support TF ops with side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931121/can-cond-support-tf-ops-with-side-effects)

```
def new_decay_step(decay_steps):
        decay_steps = decay_steps[1:]
        current_decay_step.assign(current_decay_step + 1)
        return tf.no_op()

tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.shape(decay_steps)[0], 0),
                             tf.cond(tf.greater(global_step, decay_steps[0]), new_decay_step, tf.no_op()),
tf.no_op())

p = current_decay_step
```

**Third option:** It will not work because I can't get element with `tensor[another_tensor]`.

```
    # if len(decay_steps) > (current_step + 1):
    #    if global_step > decay_steps[current_step + 1]:
    #        current_step += 1


    current_decay_step = tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.shape(current_decay_step)[0], tf.add(current_decay_step,1)),
                                 tf.cond(tf.greater(global_step, decay_steps[tf.add(current_decay_step + 1]), tf.add(current_decay_step,1), tf.add(current_decay_step,0)),
                                 tf.add(current_decay_step, 0)
```

What can I do?

**UPD:** I almost can make it with second option.

I can make

```
   def nothing: return tf.no_op()
   tf.cond(tf.greater(global_step, decay_steps[0]),
                    functools.partial(new_decay_step, decay_steps),
                    nothing)
```

But for some reason inner `tf.cond` doesn't work

For this code I get error `fn1 must be callable`

```
   def nothing: return tf.no_op()
   tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.shape(decay_steps)[0], 0),
            tf.cond(tf.greater(global_step, decay_steps[0]),
                    functools.partial(new_decay_step, decay_steps),
                    nothing),
            nothing)
```

**UPD2:** Inner `tf.cond` will not work because they return tensor and args must be functions.

I didn't check it but seems like it works (at least it doesn't crash with errors):

```
 tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(tf.shape(decay_steps)[0], 0),  tf.greater(global_step, decay_steps[0])),
                    functools.partial(new_decay_step, decay_steps),
                    nothing)
```

**UPD3:** I realized that code in **UPD2** wil not work because I can't change list inside the function.

Also I don't know what parts of `tf.logical_and` are really executed.

I made following code:

```
class ohmy:
    def __init__(self, decay_steps):
        self.decay_steps = decay_steps

    def multistep_decay(self, learning_rate, global_step, current_decay_step, decay_steps, decay_rate,
                    staircase=False, name=None):

        learning_rate = tf.convert_to_tensor(learning_rate, name="learning_rate")
        dtype = learning_rate.dtype
        global_step = tf.cast(global_step, dtype)

        decay_rate = tf.cast(decay_rate, dtype)

        def new_step():
            self.decay_steps = self.decay_steps[1:]
            current_decay_step.assign(current_decay_step + 1)
            return current_decay_step

        def curr_step():
            return current_decay_step

        current_decay_step = tf.cond(tf.logical_and(tf.greater(tf.shape(self.decay_steps)[0], 0),  tf.greater(global_step, self.decay_steps[0])),
                new_step,
                curr_step)

        a = tf.Print(global_step, [global_step], "global")
        b = tf.Print(self.decay_steps, [self.decay_steps], "decay_steps")
        c = tf.Print(current_decay_step, [current_decay_step], "step")

        with tf.control_dependencies([a, b, c, current_decay_step]):
            p = current_decay_step

            if staircase:
                p = tf.floor(p)

            return tf.mul(learning_rate, tf.pow(decay_rate, p), name=name)


decay_steps = [3,4,5,6,7]
decay_steps = tf.convert_to_tensor(decay_steps, dtype=tf.float32)
current_decay_step = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
decay_rate = 0.5

c=ohmy(decay_steps)
lr = ohmy.multistep_decay(c, 0.010, global_step, current_decay_step, decay_steps, decay_rate)
#lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(0.001, global_step=global_step, decay_steps=2, decay_rate=0.5, staircase=True)
tf.scalar_summary('learning_rate', lr)

opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
#...train loop and so on
```

It doesn't work at all. Here is output :

```
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] step[0]
I tensorflow/core/kernels/logging_ops.cc:79] global[0]
E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] The tensor returned for MergeSummary/MergeSummary:0 was not valid.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flownet_new.py", line 528, in <module>
    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 382, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 655, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 723, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 743, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: The tensor returned for MergeSummary/MergeSummary:0 was not valid.
```

As you can see there is no output of decay steps. I can't even debug it!

Now I definitely don't know how to make it with one function. 
Btw, either I do something wrong, or `tf.contrib.slim` doesn't work with learning rate decay.

For now most simple solution is make what you want in train loop as [cleros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4385912/cleros) said.

Comment: See Stackoverflow question # 33919948: You can simply make your learning rate a variable, which you can then assign with the assign_op to any value you want (as computed in tensor-free code, e.g.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can do it in this way if I will construct train loop manually. But I'm not sure that I can do it with `tf.contrib.slim.learning.train` (see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/README.md ).

Comment: Sorry, it was incorrect url. Documentation is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim

Comment: I'm not familiar with `tf.contrib.slim`. But it looks like you define the optimizer (such as AdaGrad) here: `def train_step(sess, train_op, global_step, train_step_kwargs)`, in global_step. Since you can initialize any optimizer's learning rate as a TF variable, you can initialize it like that, and then pass it into that function (which in turn is called by train, which takes these arguments in `train_step_kwargs=_USE_DEFAULT`).

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for this feature in Tensorflow and I found out it can be easily implemented using the  "tf.train.piecewise_constant" function. Here is an example from Tensorflow API: [Piece-wise constant](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/piecewise_constant)

Example: use a learning rate that's 1.0 for the first 100000 steps, 0.5 for steps 100001 to 110000, and 0.1 for any additional steps.

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
boundaries = [100000, 110000]
values = [1.0, 0.5, 0.1]
learning_rate = tf.train.piecewise_constant(global_step, boundaries, values)
```

Later, whenever we perform optimization, we make an increment of the "global_step".

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tf.train.exponential_decay()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/exponential_decay), it's exactly what you're looking for. The decayed learning rate is computed as follows:

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                    decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

Note that `decay_steps` parameter is an integer (not an array nor tensor) holding the period of iterations in which the learning rate changes. In your example `decay_steps=100`.

Comment: Sorry, but authors of net which I try to implement are using not equal intervals for decay. I told about tensor or array for this reason. For example with this function you can't decay after 100, 200, 300 and continue to 1000 without change of learning rate.

I'm almost sure that I can change other hyperparameters and net structure and get good training but firstly I wanted to check their way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `case`, `switch`, and `merge`.

For example, suppose `base_lr` is `0.1`, and `gamma` is `0.1`, you can use

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

global_step = global_step = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)

learning_rate = tf.case(
    [(tf.less(global_step, 100), lambda: tf.constant(0.1)),
     (tf.less(global_step, 200), lambda: tf.constant(0.01))],
    default=lambda: tf.constant(0.001))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 0}))   # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 1}))   # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 99}))  # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 100})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 101})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 199})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 200})) # 0.001
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 201})) # 0.001
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

global_step = global_step = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int64)

learning_rate = control_flow_ops.merge(
    [control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(0.1), 
                             tf.less(global_step, 100))[1],
     control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(0.01), 
                             tf.logical_and(tf.greater_equal(global_step, 100),
                                            tf.less(global_step, 200)))[1],
     control_flow_ops.switch(tf.constant(0.001), 
                             tf.greater_equal(global_step, 200))[1]])[0]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 0}))   # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 1}))   # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 99}))  # 0.1
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 100})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 101})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 199})) # 0.01
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 200})) # 0.001
    print(sess.run(learning_rate, {global_step: 201})) # 0.001
```

The code is tested with `tensorflow 0.12.1`.