# How to use tf.cond in combination with batching operations / queue runners

Tags: python, tensorflow

## Situation

I want to train a specific network architecture (a [GAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2661)) that needs inputs from different sources during training.

One input source is examples loaded from disk. The other source is a generator sub-network creating examples.

To choose which kind of input to feed to the network I use `tf.cond`. There is one caveat though that [has already been explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34934543/850264): `tf.cond` evaluates the inputs to both conditional branches even though only one of those will ultimately be used.

Enough setup, here is a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

BATCH_SIZE = 32

def load_input_data():
  # Normally this data would be read from disk
  data = tf.reshape(np.arange(10 * BATCH_SIZE, dtype=np.float32), shape=(10 * BATCH_SIZE, 1))
  return tf.train.batch([data], BATCH_SIZE, enqueue_many=True)

def generate_input_data():
  # Normally this data would be generated by a much bigger sub-network
  return tf.random_uniform(shape=[BATCH_SIZE, 1])

def main():
  # A bool to choose between loaded or generated inputs
  load_inputs_pred = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool, shape=[])

  # Variant 1: Call "load_input_data" inside tf.cond
  data_batch = tf.cond(load_inputs_pred, load_input_data, generate_input_data)
  # Variant 2: Call "load_input_data" outside tf.cond
  #loaded_data = load_input_data()
  #data_batch = tf.cond(load_inputs_pred, lambda: loaded_data, generate_input_data)

  init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    print(threads)

    # Get generated input data
    data_batch_values = sess.run(data_batch, feed_dict={load_inputs_pred: False})
    print(data_batch_values)

    # Get input data loaded from disk
    data_batch_values = sess.run(data_batch, feed_dict={load_inputs_pred: True})
    print(data_batch_values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

## Problem

Variant 1 does not work at all since the queue runner threads don't seem to run. `print(threads)` outputs something like `[<Thread(Thread-1, stopped daemon 140165838264064)>, ...]`.

Variant 2 does work and `print(threads)` outputs something like `[<Thread(Thread-1, started daemon 140361854863104)>, ...]`. But since `load_input_data()` has been called outside of `tf.cond`, batches of data will be loaded from disk even when `load_inputs_pred` is `False`.

Is it possible to make Variant 1 work, so that input data is only loaded when `load_inputs_pred` is `True` and not for every call to `session.run()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a queue when loading your data and follow it up with a batch input then this shouldn't be a problem as you can specify the max amount to have loaded or stored in the queue.

```
input = tf.WholeFileReader(somefilelist) # or another way to load data
return tf.train.batch(input,batch_size=10,capacity=100)
```

See here for more details:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch

---

Also there's an alternative approach that skips the tf.cond completely.  Just define two losses one that follows the data through the autoencoder and discrimator and the other that follows the data through just the discriminator.

Then it just becomes a matter of calling

```
sess.run(auto_loss,feed_dict)
```

or

```
sess.run(real_img_loss,feed_dict)
```

In this way the graph will only run through which ever loss was called upon. Let me know if this needs more explanation.

---

Lastly I think to make variant one work you need to do something like this  if you're using preloaded data.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#preloaded-data

Otherwise I'm not sure what the issue is to be honest.

Comment: The problem with batch + cond is the following: Either it doesn't work at all (variant 1) or it does work but produces batches even though the other branch of the condition is taken (variant 2). This is bad since it will read training data from disk that ends up in nirvana.
Defining two losses is indeed an option. It has a downside though: You need to duplicate the discriminator network which wastes memory on the GPU.
I only used preloaded data in my example code for simplicity, my actual code uses Tensorflow's file reading operations.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the discriminator if you use tf.VariableScope.reuse_variables()

Comment: Currently I don't think tensorflow has that good tools for memory management.  Also have you tried adding a tf.Variable before the load_input function for variant 1? Like in the preloaded data example?

Comment: Yes, I need a duplicate discriminator that shares weights with the original discriminator (like you said). That will still use quite some more memory on the GPU though. Nevertheless that's probably what I need to do if I can't figure out how to get variant 1 to work.

Comment: What do you mean with "have you tried adding a tf.Variable before the load_input function"?

Comment: add this 
input_data = tf.Variable(load_inputs_pred, trainable=False, collections=[])   
before data batch and this after the sess is created
sess.run(input_data.initializer,
           feed_dict={data_initializer: training_data})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123546/discussion-between-steven-and-daniel).

Comment: @Daniel cond is not lazy in the same way as `if`, the node in the non-running branch will not be executed, but its dependencies will be

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Exactly, that's why Variant 1 makes sure that there are no dependencies. But somehow the queue runners for the batching operation won't run then and I don't understand why.