# Prevent evaluation of Op in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I like to exchange Ops in every epoch in Tensorflow. Currently I implemented this by using

```
control_flow_ops.cond(tf.less(epoch, float()), op1, op2)
```

However, it seems like the non-used Ops are still evaluated, which slows down the training process significantly. Is there a way to reduce this overhead?

Comment: see: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond

Answer (score 0):

Think of `control_flow_ops.cond(tf.less(epoch, float()), op1, op2)` as an equivalent of Python's `a if f(x) else b` where `a` and `b` are variables. At the point `a` and `b` already store some value, so both branches are evaluated. You need to do something like `create_op1()` instead of `op1` to only evaluate one branch. More details in mrry's post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931121/can-cond-support-tf-ops-with-side-effects/34934543#34934543)